# How can identify a blank line in C++?

Tags: c++, file, input

I'm reading in information from a file. I need a counter that counts how many text filled lines there are. I need that counter to stop if there is any blank line (even if there are text filled lines after that blank line).

How would I do this? Because I'm not exactly sure how to identify a blank line to stop the counter there.

Comment: How are you reading the file?

Comment: I would look for carriage return or line feed characters (e.g. `\r` or `\r\n` or just `\n`).

Comment: Just as a note: if you read it as text you won't have to care about the differences of `\r`, `\r\n` or `\n` like @GIJoe seems to suggest. It will all be `\n` in your program.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the OP doesn't show any efforts what they've been trying themselves.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I'd suggest reading http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223480/to-flag-or-not-to-flag-question-that-dont-show-own-effort/223482#223482.  To be clear, I don't like them either, but it's not a direct reason to close.

Comment: @JohnH OK, more or less. I was considering _'lacks sufficient information to diagnose ...'_, but decided to write my own reasoning to push the OP. I think it's still perfectly OK, **you might choose** a different reasoning for close voting the question.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ It absolutely doesn't fall into the category of lacking sufficient information (as the 6 answers below attest to), as it is answerable, but I don't agree with your close reason either (although I agree with the sentiment).

Comment: @JohnH At least it's a democratic process, and I no one else will agree with me, there's no bad done at all ;) ...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ It does cause a problem, as you're needlessly pushing questions into the close queue just because they show a lack of effort.  That means several other people have to deal with it.

Comment: I really don't mean just pile on questions on you guys. I do know how do read in files so I wasn't asking for any code for reading in files (but I do appreciate those who did write some). I was merely asking how to identify a blank line and I'm sure if I had sufficient time to jot some ideas down or do some googling I can find it. While I do understand some of you being upset with me, I also find don't find the demeaning tone of some to be very useful especially with so many people just starting to code, it just doesn't create a good environment. Sorry if I was out of line though I'm new here.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using `std::getline` then you can just detect an empty line by checking if the `std::string` you have just read is empty.

```
std::ifstream stream;
stream.open("file.txt");
std::string text;
while(std::getline(stream,text))
    if(!text.size())
        std::cout << "empty" << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest using `std::getline` for it:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    unsigned counter = 0;
    std::string line;

    while (std::getline(std::cin, line) && line != "")
        ++counter;

    std::cout << counter << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

---

Since @Edward made a comment about handling whitespace and it might be important. When lines with only whitespaces are considered as "empty lines" too I'd suggest changing it to:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>

int main()
{
    unsigned counter = 0;
    std::string line;

    while (std::getline(std::cin, line) &&
           std::find_if_not( line.begin(), line.end(), std::isspace != line.end()) {
        ++counter;
    }

    std::cout << counter << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

It's quite verbose, but the advantage is that it uses `std::isspace` to handle all different kind of spaces (e.g. `' '`, `'\t'`, `'\v'`, etc...) and you don't have to worry if you handle them correctly.

Comment: If you need to detect lines with only whitespace as blank, you could modify the while loop like so:
     while ( std::getline(std::cin, line) ) {
     if (std::string::npos == line.find_first_not_of(" \t")) ++counter;
 }

Answer (score 0):

In C++ 11 you can use,

```
std::isblank
```

Answer (score 0):

In a loop, read all lines, one-by-one, into a single `string` variable. You can use a `std::getline` function for that.

Each time after reading a line into that variable, check its `length`. If it's zero, then the line is empty, and in that case `break` the loop.

However, checking for empty lines like is not always really right thing. If you are sure that the lines will be empty, then it's OK. But if your "empty" lines can contain whitespaces,

```
123 2 312 3213
12 3123 123
              // <---  Here are SPACEs. Is it "empty"?
123 123 213
123 21312 3
```

then you might need to not check for "zero-length", but rather whether "all characters are whitespaces".

Answer (score 0):

No error checking, no protection, just a simple example... It is not tested, but you get the gist.

```
#incldue <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  string str = "";
  int blank = 0, text = 0;
  ifstream myfile;
  myfile.open("pathToFile");
  while(getline(myfile,str))
  {
    if(str == "")
    {
      ++blank;
    }
    else
    {
      ++text;
    }
  }
  cout << "Blank: " << blank << "\t" << "With text: " << text;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply check the string length and use a line counter. When the string length is zero (i.e., the string is blank) print the line counter. Sample code is provided for your reference:

```
// Reading a text file

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main () {
    string line;
    ifstream myfile ("example.txt");
    int i = 0;
    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        while (getline (myfile, line))
        {
            i++;
            // cout << line << '\n';
            if (line.length() == 0)
                break;
        }
        cout << "blank line found at line no. " << i << "\n";
        myfile.close();
    }
    else
        cout << "Unable to open file";

     return 0;
}
```